# Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to DOMXPath::query() must be an instance of DOMNode

Tags: php

I am getting the error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to DOMXPath::query() must be an instance of DOMNode

Am I querying the scrape incorrectly? The error applies to both the `get name of the item` and the `get every item image` lines. Before this I have created an array from a json file. The purpose of this code is to scrape data from a site dynamically, with variations that are set from the json file.

```
//loop through all the items (LR)
foreach($json_array as $iscrape){

    // Site Source (LR)
    $iscrapeurl="The URL is here (this is removed for stackoverflow)" . $iscrape['name'];
    $iscrapesource = file_get_contents($iscrapeurl);

    // Create DOM document (LR)
    $iscrape_doc = new DOMDocument();

    // Disable libxml errors (LR)
    libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);

    //if any html is returned (LR)
    if(!empty($iscrapesource)){

        // Load HTML that was returned (LR)
        $iscrape_doc->loadHTML($iscrapesource);

        // Remove errors (LR)
        libxml_clear_errors(); 

        // allows us to do some queries with the DOM Document (LR)
        $iscrape_xpath = new DOMXPath($iscrape_doc);

        // Select every list item (LR)
        $details = $iscrape_xpath->query('//div[@id="profile"]');

        // If there are list items (LR)
        if($details->length > 0){   

          // Get the name of the item (LR)
          $name = $iscrape_xpath->query('//div[@class="heading"]', $iscrape)->item(0)->nodeValue;

         // Get every item image (LR)
         $image = $iscrape_xpath->query('//div[@class="profile_section_content"]/img', $iscrape)->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: What is `$iscrape`? It is not defined anywhere in this code

Comment: I apologize, iscrape is part of a foreach loop that comes just before this code.

Comment: So, find out the type of each iteration of `$iscrape` and make sure it is always the type required.

Comment: I've worked it out. all fixed. Will post the fix in 8 hours when i am able to respond to my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've fixed it.

Though I should post a reply to my own question in case anyone else is attempting to scrape data off another website.

A for each loop is required for each piece of data (which makes sense when you think about it) - I have added the lines commented 'loop through all items' and changed the $iscrape to $i.

```
        // Select every list item (LR)
        $details = $iscrape_xpath->query('//div[@id="profile"]');

        // If there are list items (LR)
        if($details->length > 0){   

             //loop through all the items (LR)
             foreach($details as $i){

                  // Get the name of the item (LR)
                  $name = $iscrape_xpath->query('//div[@class="heading"]', $i)->item(0)->nodeValue;
```